# Using Java 8 Streams replace Characters in a String if found in a list of Characters

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Input = `M+a?i*n S=t`

expectedvalue = `M a i n s t`

Compare each character from **Input** with the following list of characters and if found replace it with space and the ouput should be **expectedValue**.

#### ., (, :, ;, ), {, *, +, _, -, !, ?,~, %, =, ¦, ¬, ¢, \, <, >, &, ,, }, $, '', `, @, [, ], ±, Ñ, P¦,  _, $

Comment: Looking at your character list, it feels as though you are going about this backwards. Change every character that *isn't* in a whitelist (A-Z, a-z, ...) to a space.

Comment: I can't tell why is there is `java-stream` tag here

Comment: Maybe because it's homework and it has to be done with streams. Also, whitelist approach won't cut it I think. The problem specifically asks for a blacklist, and since the input charset is unknown, it would have to be a looong whitelist. But @Eugene 's regex approach could be changed, just concat all the forbidden chars with `|`

Comment: Kotha, is using streams really a requirement? It could be done by `String.replaceAll()` easily.

Comment: It’s an odd list. `_` appears twice and `P¦` is not a single character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming

```
String input;
List<Character> forbidden;
```

your can use

```
String result = input.replaceAll(
     forbidden.stream()
              .map(String::valueOf).map‌​(Pattern::quote)
              .collect(Collectors.joining("|")),
     " ");
```

It converts each forbidden `Character` to a `String` using `String.valueOf(…)`, then uses `Pattern.quote(…)` to convert them to a quoted pattern string, which ensures that the characters are not interpreted as special regex constructs, then all are joined using `|` which means “or” in a regex pattern. Then, `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)` does the actual job.

An alternative without regex (“pure stream operation”) would be

```
String result = input.chars()
    .map(c -> forbidden.contains((char)c)? ' ': c)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, c) -> sb.append((char)c), StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
```

This straight-forwardly iterates over all characters, checks whether they are contained in the `forbidden` collection and replaces them with a space if they are, and finally collects the mapped characters to a new `String`. It would be more efficient when `forbidden` gets changed to a `Set<Character>` rather than `List<Character>` due to the time complexity of `contains`, which is invoked for every character.

Answer (score 1):

Seems trivial enough:

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " "));
```

OR

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", " "));
```

Comment: You could use the list of forbidden chars by concating them with "|". Then you would make sure to only replace forbidden chars. Furthermore, this solution does not lowercase chars as shown in the example.

Comment: the list I need to search is a custom list.so can't use RegEx to replace all non Alpha Caracters

Comment: Of course you can, use ".|(|:|andSoOn" as your regex

Comment: `input.replaceAll(forbidden.stream().map(String::valueOf).map(Pattern::quote) .collect(Collectors.joining("|")), " ")`

Comment: @Holger That is a perfect solution for me. It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Can you please make this is an answer, so that I can accept.